# A client between two servers?

Tags: node.js, client-server, tcpserver

I'm fairly new to node js and I need to solve a problem. I have two tcp servers that can send out messages. I need a component between them (a client?): when the first server sends out a message, this middle component must take it (because I need to parse that) and send it to the second server and viceversa (from second server to first server). How to do this in node? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

a basic tcp 
server, but for some reason omit a client connecting to it.
In your middleware, you'll have to have a client that gets the message and forward it to the other server.

At the server

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

At the client

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood this. Your solution is to put a server and a client as a middleware? The first and the second server are immutable and on separate nodes. So, if I understood correctly you say that I need a server in the middle and when server receives messages, a client connected to it do the sending part.. But how can I connect to these two servers? How the middleware server you propose receives messages?

Comment: No, I purpose a single client as I wrote, the code is an example for how to use client/server with node